# RedLaser Sdk UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, exception, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am using the Android Licensed RedLaser sdk. I tried so many things but still i am getting the UnsatisfiedLinkError. Please help me out.

stacktrace is below :

```
04-03 14:06:58.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1005): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to     uncaught exception
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at com.ebay.redlasersdk.BarcodeEngine.<init>(BarcodeEngine.java:50)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at com.ebay.redlasersdk.scanner.CaptureActivityHandler.<init>(CaptureActivityHandler.java:48)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at com.ebay.redlasersdk.scanner.BarcodeScanActivity.initCamera(BarcodeScanActivity.java:382)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at com.ebay.redlasersdk.scanner.BarcodeScanActivity.surfaceCreated(BarcodeScanActivity.java:246)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:454)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:287)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1349)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1114)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library redlaser not found
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:489)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     at com.ebay.redlasersdk.scanner.NewLaserScanner.<clinit>(NewLaserScanner.java:190)
04-03 14:06:58.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1005):     ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add a `NDK Library` to your application. You should place this library (which usually has the .so extendsion) inside the `libs/armeabi` folder, inside the root of your project.

If you still get this error after this, you should also use the following static code block, inside any class to be sure that your library is loaded:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("your_library_name");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply :) It was because of some other reasons that is solved now .

Comment: Could you mention how did you solve it? Having same issue here